# Getting error Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * @author  SUBHA FAIRUZ
 *
 */
public class calculation {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i;
        for( i=0; i<=4;i++) {
            System.out.println("1.ADDITION\n2.SUBTRACTION\n3.MULTIPLICATION\n4.DIVISION\n5.EXIT");
            System.out.print("Choose Your Operator:");  
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option= input.nextInt();

            if(option==5)
                System.exit(0);

            while(option>=6 || option<=0){
                System.out.println("Please select one(1) to five(5).");
                option= input.nextInt();

            }
            add addobj= new add();
            subtract subobj= new subtract();
            multiplication mulobj= new multiplication();
            division divobj= new division();

            if(option!=5)
                System.out.println("Enter two number:");
                int number1= input.nextInt();
                int number2=input.nextInt();

            switch(option) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Addition:"+"("+ number1 +") + ("+ number2 +") =  "+ addobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Subtraction:"+"("+ number1 +") - ("+ number2 +") = "+ subobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Multiplication:"+"("+ number1 +") * ("+ number2 +") = "+ mulobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;

            case 4:
                while(number1==0){
                System.out.println("Please enter non-zero value of first number:");
                number1= input.nextInt();
                number2= input.nextInt();

                }
                System.out.println("Division:"+ "("+ number1 +") / ("+ number2 +") = "+ divobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            case 5:
                    System.exit(0);
                //break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            input.close();
        }
        return ;
    }
}
```

[My code is working fine but i'm getting one warning that i didn't closed my scanner.
But when i'm closing the Scanner,it's giving me another error!! Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKvC2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when you try to call `nextInt` when there is no such element that you have inputted. You could avoid the issue by making use of check with a method call on scanner instance method `hasNextInt`. I think the problem is with your division operation, where you should check for divisor being 0 instead of dividend and only take divisors new value instead of both.

Couple of things about your code:

a. You are creating transient object within for loop. You could create them outside the loop.
b. You shouldn't need to close scanner if you use `try with resource` construct which is available since JDK 7.
c. If you ever want to close scanner, you should close it in finally block where it may happen you get an exception and you may end up leaking the resource.
d. Your first if condition for checking `option == 5` should be after your while loop `while(option>=6 || option<=0){`

To sum up, this could be the code to solve your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    add addobj= new add();//Use camel case naming convention for classes
    subtract subobj= new subtract();
    multiplication mulobj= new multiplication();
    division divobj= new division();
    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for(int i=0; i<=4;i++) {
            System.out.println("1.ADDITION\n2.SUBTRACTION\n3.MULTIPLICATION\n4.DIVISION\n5.EXIT");
            System.out.print("Choose Your Operator:");  
            int option= input.nextInt();

            while(option>=6 || option<=0){
                System.out.println("Please select one(1) to five(5).");
                option= input.nextInt();
            }

            if(option==5)
                return;

            System.out.println("Enter two number:");
            int number1= input.nextInt();
            int number2=input.nextInt();

            switch(option) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Addition:"+"("+ number1 +") + ("+ number2 +") =  "+ addobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Subtraction:"+"("+ number1 +") - ("+ number2 +") = "+ subobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Multiplication:"+"("+ number1 +") * ("+ number2 +") = "+ mulobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            case 4:
                while(number2==0){
                    System.out.println("Please enter non-zero value of second number:");
                    number2= input.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Division:"+ "("+ number1 +") / ("+ number2 +") = "+ divobj.result(number1,number2));
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is " with(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))" ?

Comment: thank you so much for your effort. i'm a new learner and following your instructions.

Comment: great going @subhafairuz, your code is perfect! you will get these concepts cleared down with more practice. Don't hesitate to call for help if you need from me.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.NoSuchElementException is a RuntimeException which can be thrown by different classes in Java like Iterator, Enumerator, Scanner or StringTokenizer.

All of those classes has method to fetch next element or next tokens if underlying data-structure doesn't have any element Java throws "java.util.NoSuchElementException".

Most common example of this iterating over hashmap without checking if there is any element or not and that's why it's advised to use hashNext() before calling next() on Iterator.

---

Initilize you scanner outside of for loop

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for( i=0; i<=4;i++) {

}
```

Close your scanner outside for loop.

```
for( i=0; i<=4;i++) {

}
input.close();
```

Scanner class read data stream in advance to provide better performance. which can be issue over here.

Comment: if you face same issue please commnt here with description of your issue.

Comment: i also tried that but doesn't solve the issue. Gives me same error

Comment: did you defined your scanner outside for loop and close it outside for loop. remove scanner initializer and close method from inside for loop. It should work.